# Сортировка массива в java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Java. Прошу помощи. Необходимо массив из чисел int отсортировать в возрастающем порядке с помощью определенного способа - первым шагом сравнить и обменять элементы i и i+1, где i - четное число. Вторым шагом - где i - нечетное число. Повторять пока массив не будет отсортирован. Сделать надо с помощью дополнительного метода.
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ни делал - выдает ошибку array out of bounds.

```
    public static void firstMethod(int[] A) {
    int z, j;
    for (j=0; j<A.length; j=j+2);
    if(A[j]<A[j+1]){
        z = A[j];
        A[j] = A[j+1];
        A[j+1] = z;
    }
    for (j=1; j<A.length-1; j=j+2);
    if(A[j]<A[j+1]){
        z = A[j];
        A[j] = A[j+1];
        A[j+1] = z;
    }
```

Comment: во-первых, у вас точка с запятой после цикла, т.е. оба оператора `if` выполнятся не в циклах, а по одному разу, после того, как циклы увеличат `j` до перехода за размер массива. Во-вторых, вы оба раза лезете в `j+1`, но в первом цикле почему-то проверяете, что `j < A.length`, что тоже даст вам выход за границы массива.

Comment: @zRrr большое спасибо, глупая ошибка. Но не могли бы вы еще подсказать, как с помощью данного способа заставить программу выполнять сортировку определенное количество раз, до конечного результата? А то, например, сейчас массив сортируется частично. Простите за столь глупые вопросы, с программированием пока на "вы."

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы описали довольно сильно похоже на сортировку [пузырьком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), но несколько отличается (в сортировке пузырьком предполагается проход элементов подряд, следствием чего является получение за каждую итерацию максимального/минимального элемента из просматриваемых, здесь же несколько другая формулировка, а в итоге алгоритм совсем другой). 
P.S. Уточните, правильно ли вы поняли формулировку, если да, то реализация `sort()` вам подойдет, но если это, все-таки, пузырек, то воспользуейтесь методом `bubbleSort()`.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] massive = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

        System.out.print("Начальное состояние массива:        ");
        showout(massive);

        sort(massive);

        System.out.print("Состояние массива после сортировки: ");
        showout(massive);
    }

    /** реализует ту сортировку, которую вы описали */
    private static void sort(int[] massive)
    {
        boolean isAlreadySorted;
        do
        {
            isAlreadySorted = sort(massive, 0) & sort(massive, 1);
        } while (!isAlreadySorted);
    }

    /** при необходимости меняет местами соседние элементы массива massive начиная с позиции startIndex и далее через одну */
    private static boolean sort(int[] massive, int startIndex)
    {
        boolean isAlreadySorted = true;
        for (int index = startIndex; index < massive.length - 1; index += 2)
        {
            if (massive[index] > massive[index + 1])
            {
                isAlreadySorted = false;
                swap(massive, index, index + 1);
            }
        }
        return isAlreadySorted;
    }

    /** меняет местами элементы массива massive с индексами leftIndex и rightIndex */
    private static void swap(int[] massive, int leftIndex, int rightIndex)
    {
        massive[leftIndex] ^= massive[rightIndex];
        massive[rightIndex] ^= massive[leftIndex];
        massive[leftIndex] ^= massive[rightIndex];
    }

    /** выводит элементы массива на экран */
    private static void showout(int[] massive)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < massive.length - 1; ++index)
        {
            System.out.print(massive[index] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(massive[massive.length - 1]);
    }

    /** обычная сортировка пузырьком */
    private static void bubbleSort(int[] massive)
    {
        boolean isAlreadySorted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < massive.length - 1 && !isAlreadySorted; i++)
        {
            isAlreadySorted = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < massive.length - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (massive[j] > massive[j + 1])
                {
                    swap(massive, j, j + 1);
                    isAlreadySorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не могу найти что это за оператор: `^=`

Comment: @Yukon Это [исключающее или (xor)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.98.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B0.D1.8E.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D0.98.D0.9B.D0.98_.28XOR.29). Основывается на свойстве обратимости отображения (операции), т.е. если применять данную операцию снова, то получите начальное значение. Особо большого смысла здесь в этом нет, просто это довольно эффективный способ обменять значениях 2 целочисленных переменных не заводя 3тью.

Comment: возможно стоит поменять в `sort(massive, 0) && sort(massive, 1)` `&&` на `&`, сейчас сортировка по нечетным индексам вызывается только если сортировка по четным не перемещала элементы.

Comment: @zRrr А ведь и правда накосячил с короткой схемой вычислений :) Спасибо, подправил.

Answer (score 2):

Обычная сортировка пузырьком

```
boolean changes;
do {
    changes = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
            int _current = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = _current;
            changes = true;
        }
    }

}
while (changes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
public static void firstMethod(int[] a) {
    boolean isSorted = false;

    while (!isSorted) {
        isSorted = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i += 2) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i += 2) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Правда цикл while пробегает один лишний раз, чтобы удостовериться, что изменений больше происходить не будет.

Comment: `{1, 4, 6, 2, 3}` не отсортирует, поскольку пары, начинающиеся с нечетного индекса в порядке.

Comment: @zRrr логично. Ок. Тогда некрасиво, зато уже точно. Сейчас подправлю. Пока больше ничего в голову под утро не лезет...